# Run multiple queries each selecting each respective Nth row?

Tags: sql-server, modulo, sql-server-2014

`Related to "[Selecting every nth row from SQL Server 2008 query result where table does not have row id column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407693/selecting-every-nth-row-from-sql-server-2008-query-result-where-table-does-not-h)", I understand that doing the following would select every 4th row.

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 0`

But what I want to do is run 4 separate queries that select the 4th row starting at 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.  Would it look like this?

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 0`

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 1`

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 2`

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 3`

or maybe

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID + 1 % 4 = 0`

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID + 2 % 4 = 0`

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID + 3 % 4 = 0`

`SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID + 4 % 4 = 0`

???

Comment: So if your ID are {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},  what are the result you want? starting 1: {4,8,12}  starting 2; {5,9,13} starting 3: {6,10,14} starting 4: { 7,11} ??

Comment: Query A should get records 1, 5, 9, 13.  Query B should get 2, 6, 10, 14.  Query C should get 3, 7, 11 and Query D would get 4, 8, 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

Given 20 rows and 4 iterations:

Rows 1,5,9,13,17:   `SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 1`

Rows 2,6,10,14,18: `SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 2`

Rows 3,7,11,15,19: `SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 3`

Rows 4,8,12,16,20: `SELECT ID, Whatever FROM MyTable WHERE ID % 4 = 0`

Comment: Yes I got that query too, but understand wrong the required output. :(. That is why i make the query too complicated to remove the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Test it on SQL 2008 [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/4)

Table definition

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[testSQL];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testSQL](
    [ID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into testSQL values (1);
insert into testSQL values (2);
insert into testSQL values (3);
insert into testSQL values (4);
insert into testSQL values (5);
insert into testSQL values (6);
insert into testSQL values (7);
insert into testSQL values (8);
insert into testSQL values (9);
insert into testSQL values (10);
insert into testSQL values (11);
insert into testSQL values (12);
insert into testSQL values (13);
insert into testSQL values (14);
insert into testSQL values (15);
```

You only need to create a Function receiving `@skip` as parameter

```
DECLARE @skip int;
DECLARE @total int;
SET @skip = 2; -- how many row will you skip in your case {0,1,2,3}

SELECT @total = (
    SELECT  count(*)
    FROM testSQL
) - @skip;   -- total rows - number row you want skip

-- here begin the magic
WITH SkipN (ID)  -- skip first N rows
AS
(
    SELECT TOP (@total) * 
    FROM testSQL
    ORDER BY ID DESC -- skip rows will be at the end
)   
, final AS ( -- assign new id
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as new_id, * 
    FROM SkipN
)
SELECT *
FROM final
WHERE new_id % 4 = 0
```

RESULT for @skip = 2

[image]

Comment: edit: Oh I think I get it.  Not sure I can create functions but I'll see.

Comment: This was way more complex than what I needed, but kudos :)